# Uncertainty on a poisson distributed probability?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, standard-deviation

I know that the standard deviation is the square root of the mean if the random variable is poisson distributed, but do you assign that to the probability of a certain event? Let's say that for the random variable X, the mean is 4.6 with r event = 3. I calculate the probability to be 0.163. Should I assign the square root of 4.6 as an uncertainty to this probability? My teacher is very strict with uncertainties so I feel...uncertain about reporting probabilities without one.

Comment: What do you mean assigning an "uncertainty to this probability"? A Probability is already a way to measure uncertainty. The standard deviation is another way to measure uncertainty, capturing "spread" of the random variable $X$.

Comment: In particular, you computed the *precise* probability under your model; where is the "uncertainty" in that computation?